# Query always outputs Probmlem

Tags: php, html, css

Does anyone know what the problem in this query is, everytime i fill the form it outouts the script "Problem!"

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//getting the text data from the fields
$title = $_POST['title'];
$cat= $_POST['cat'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$status = $_POST['status'];



//getting the image from the field
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/drinks/$image");


 $insert_product = "insert into drinks (title,cat,image,desc,qty,price,status) values ('$title','$cat','$image','$desc','$qty','$price','$status')";

 $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

 if($insert_pro){

 echo "<script>alert('Drink Has been inserted!')</script>";
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php?viewdrink','_self')</script>";

 }
 else{
     echo "<script>alert('Problem!')</script>";
 }
}
```

how can  improve this code to make it work.

Comment: Do you know how to check for the real errors? You do have one, a major one.

Comment: I don't know, var_dump()

Comment: what is `$con`?

Comment: Maybe check the erro.log, enable error_reporting(E_ALL); or 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Dozens of stuff could go wrong. Your DB might be disconnected, DB table/fields do not exist, etc

Comment: @SamyBencherif $con is the database connection from that is included before this code

Comment: What he means is that can you please update your code to **show** `$con`. The problem could be in there.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Also, I'm not sure if this is browser side code or not, but if it is, you can try using `console.log` as an easy way to debug. Eg `console.log($insert_pro)`

Comment: @SamyBencherif the $con works as the other php code is working but just this submit code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC` is a MySQL reserved word, it must be wrapped in ticks if you want to keep on using that column's name.

```
$insert_product = "insert into drinks (title,cat,image,`desc`,qty,price,status)....";
```

Having used `mysqli_error($con)` on the query (in the `else{...}`), it would have signaled the syntax error.

You're also open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

If that still fails, make sure that there is no character being inserted that will cause an injection and that all arrays contain value. In any case, you should be escaping all values inserted in your database.

Use PHP's error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thanks bro it helped